# Error on executing selenium

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium

I am using Firefox-53 ,Selenium-3.4 and on executing below code i got an error.

```
{

    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "D:\\Selenium\\geckodriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver ;
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();driver.get("http://www.store.demoqa.com");
}
enter code here
```

Error-Usage:

```
enter code here
D:\Selenium\geckodriver.exe`enter code here` [OPTIONS]`enter code here`
D:\Selenium\geckodriver.exe: Unknown option --port=26528`enter code here`
Exception in thread "main"`enter code here` org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException:`enter code here` org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException:`enter code here` Connect to localhost:26528 [localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] failed: Connection refused

enter code here
```

Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: close all your command prompts that run selenium standalone and try again

Comment: Remove the text enter code here at the end of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Seems the 'enter code here' part is should be done. You can easly find the correct example and change it for you gaol.

For examle,

http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/how-to-use-geckodriver/

```
package seleniumPrograms;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
public class Gecko_Driver {

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "D:\\\\ToolsQA\\trunk\\Library\\drivers\\geckodriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("http://www.toolsqa.com");

    Thread.sleep(5000);
    driver.quit();
}
}
```